# Does the difficulty setting affect the experience gained?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I´m playing the game on Normal before I start on Nightmare, but I´m curious to know if the leveling up is the same in all difficulty settings. Do you get the same amount of experience in every difficulty level, or you get more in Nightmare or something?

Comment: You got the same amount of XP on Nightmare in the other two games, but I don't know if that's still true in this one.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I remember in Dragon Age: Origins it was the same. But i´m not sure if this one is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty does not affect the amount of experience or loot gained in Inquisition. Most say that playing on a harder difficulty, however, make it a more immersive and realist experience.